# How to limit number of elements in a stream responsively?Java8

Tags: java-8

The problem I am having is turning this block of code into Java8 streams.Basically I have a list of cells that are either dead(false) or alive(true) and I need to check how many neighbours are alive for a given cell.

```
private static int checkMyLivingNeighbours(Cell cell,List<Cell> currentcells){

    int neighbours = 0;

    for (int y = cell.getY() - 1; y <= cell.getY() + 1; y++) {
        for (int x = cell.getX() - 1; x <= cell.getX() + 1; x++) {
            if(x!=cell.getX() || y!=cell.getY()){
                for (Cell nowcell : currentcells) {
                    if (nowcell.getX() == x && nowcell.getY() == y) {
                        if (nowcell.getStatus()) {
                            neighbours++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return neighbours;
}
```

I have tried something like this

```
private static void checkaliveneighbours(Cell cell,List<Cell> generation){

    generation.stream().forEach(n->IntStream.range(cell.getY()-1,cell.getY()+1).
                    forEach(y -> IntStream.range(cell.getX()-1,cell.getX()+1)
                            .forEach(x->{if(n.getX()==x && n.getY()==y && n.getStatus())System.out.println(n.getDisplaychar());})));;//
}
```

where I am calling it like such

```
    checkaliveneighbours(generation.get(0),generation);
```

SO I do get a print for the alive CELL but I actually need the total nr of alive CELLS surrounding the CELL being passed in and not just a print if the cell passed in is alive or not. Therefor the question how to limit number of elements in a stream(just the surrounding cells) responsively(based on the individual cell being passed in).

Here is the cell class

```
public class Cell {

private int x;
private int y;
private boolean alive;

public Cell(){}


public Cell(String x, String y, boolean alive ) {
    this.x = Integer.valueOf(x);
    this.y = Integer.valueOf(y);
    this.alive = alive;

}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(String x) {
    this.x = Integer.valueOf(x);
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(String y) {
    this.y = Integer.valueOf(y);
}

public boolean getStatus() {
    return alive;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.alive = status;
}

public char getDisplaychar() {

    if(getStatus())
        return 'X';
    else
        return '.';
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, by "limiting" you mean using `Stream.filter()` to filter only neighbors. Then you want to sum all living neighbors. I'd begin by defining a method that will return whether a specified cell is a neighboring cell or not:

```
private static boolean isNeighbor(final Cell cell, final Cell candidate) {
      for (int y = cell.getY() - 1; y <= cell.getY() + 1; y++) {
        for (int x = cell.getX() - 1; x <= cell.getX() + 1; x++) {
            if (x != cell.getX() || y != cell.getY()) {
                if (candidate.getX() == x && candidate.getY() == y) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you can easily filter your list and compute the sum like so:

```
int sum = generation.stream()
            .filter(c -> isNeighbor(cell, c))
            .mapToInt(c -> c.getStatus() ? 1 : 0)
            .sum();
```

**Edit:** If you're looking for a pure Java 8 solution for `isNeighbor`:

```
    private boolean isNeighbor(final Cell cell, final Cell candidate) {
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(cell.getX() - 1, cell.getX() + 1)
            .anyMatch(x -> IntStream.rangeClosed(cell.getY() - 1, cell.getY() + 1)
                    .anyMatch(y -> (x != cell.getX() || y != cell.getY()) &&
                            x == candidate.getX() && y == candidate.getY()));
    }
```

Comment: Actually i was looking for a way to do the checking if a cell is neighbour and counting the alive neighbors using just Java8 but I guess I have to do some part of it the old way. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide a pure Java 8 stream oriented solution for `isNeighbor`

Comment: One more thing that I just realized, the IntStream.range is actually excluding the last interval. In order to get all the surrounding neighbours it needs to be IntStream.rangeClosed() so all y and x coordinates will be checked.